# Galois extension is (not) transitive

Tags: galois-theory

Let $ K/ L /F $ be fields. If $K / L$ is Galois and $ L / F $ is Galois, then $ K / F$ is Galois. We mentioned this very quickly in today's class without justifying. But I have trouble seeing this. Any help is appreciated.

Our definition for $ K / F$ being Galois is the $F$-automorphism group $G = G( K / F) : = \{ \sigma \in aut (G) : \sigma_F = id_F \}$ fixes only $F$, i.e. $ \{ x \in K : \sigma (x) = x \text { for all } \sigma \in G  \} = F$.

But we also showed that $ K /F$ is Galois if and only if $ K/F$ is normal and separable.

Comment: It would probably help any answerers to know what exactly what definition you have of being Galois (and, probably, if you are only considering finite extensions)

Comment: Galoisness is *not* transitive.

Comment: Not true, as @Matt points out in his response. It’s also an error that’s all too often made.

Comment: Thank you for all of you who answers!

Comment: Galoisity? ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not true.  E.g. $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1+2i})$ is Galois over $\mathbb Q(i)$, which is Galois over $\mathbb Q$.  But $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1+2i})$ is *not* Galois over
$\mathbb Q$.

---

Another example, maybe easier to check:  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}) \supset
\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})\supset \mathbb Q$.

The Galois closure will of the first field over $\mathbb Q$ will contain
$\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2}}$ as well; but this is not a real number, whereas
$\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ consists entirely of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I see that $ \mathbb Q ( \sqrt { 1 + 2i } )$ is not Galois over $\mathbb Q $?

Comment: @user112564: Dear user, Its Galois closure will also contain $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1-2i})$, and hence also $\sqrt{5}$.   If it were already Galois, then (for degree reasons) it would have to equal $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{5})$.  But you can check (with a little effort) that no element in this field squares to give $1 + 2i$.  (There are other ways to see this that use a little more number theory.  And there are surely other examples that are easier to check; this is just the first one that came to mind.  Actually, I added another one.)  Regards,

Comment: Perhaps an easier example is $K=\Bbb Q(\root4\of 2)$, $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$, $F=\Bbb Q$. The splitting field of $f(x)=x^4-2$ is $\Bbb Q(\root4\of 2,i)$, after all. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Dear Ted, Indeed.  I added another more easily checked example too.  (I guess it's easier to tell real from imaginary than to look at the splitting behaviour of primes above $5$!)  Cheers,

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much! Also thanks to Ted Shifrin.

Answer (score 9):

In the book Abstract Algebra, third edition, by David S. Dummit and Richard M. Foote, they mention the example $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ as a pair of Galois extensions which are **not** transitive:

> The field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ since any automorphism is determined by where it sends $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and of the four possibilities $\{\pm\sqrt[4]{2},\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}\}$, only two are elements of the field (the two real roots).