# If K $\subset$ L, K Galois over F, L is a splitting field of f(x) over F, can we say L Galois over F

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $f(X) \in F[X]$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $F$, $L$ a splitting field of $f(X)$ over $F$, and $\alpha \in L$ a root of $f(X)$.  If $K$ is any Galois extension of $F$ contained in $L$, Can we draw the conclusion that $L$ is Galois over $F$?

This is part of a problem from Dummit&Foote(14.2 28). The hint of the problem says that If $H$ is the subgroup of the Galois group of $L$ over $F$ corresponding to $K$ then blablabla. I solve the problem via following the hint. However, the hint presumes that $L$ is Galois over $F$ and I use this result frequently in my proof. However, I am not sure that the statement $L$ is Galois over $F$ is true. Can anyone give any-counter example or hint how to prove the statement?

Comment: There is something wrong with your problem statement. The field $K$ is not involved at all.

Comment: @ Michael Burr Char not necessarily be zero

Comment: Do you mean either of these? [Splitting field implies Galois extension](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95131/splitting-field-implies-galois-extension) or [Galois extension is transitive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776441/galois-extension-is-transitive)

Comment: @Brandon Carter if K plays no role, then I think I can't directly draw the conclusion that L is Galois over F since f(x) is not necessarily separable.

Comment: @Michael Burr I am sorry that none of them are equivalent to the statement.~

Comment: $K$ plays no role since $K=F$ is Galois over $F$.

Comment: @Gregory Grant great idea! Thanks a lot! so the statement is false?

Comment: Yeah since it's not true that a splitting field is necessarily Galois.